# Como fazer um EditText estilo Material Design?

Tags: android, android-layout

Alguém poderia me dar uma ideia de como posso fazer esse 
plain text:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Esse EditText (Não plain text) faz parte dos Widgets do material design presentes nas API 21+

Você pode utilizá-los em API's mais antigas adicionando a biblioteca de Suporte como dependência.

**Layout.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/inputGroup"
                >
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/inputXpto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:hint="@string/procurando_por_algo"
                    />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

No arquivo build.gradle do seu **APP**:

Adicione essa linha nas dependências (`dependencies`):

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```